# How to set the vagrant user to use /bin/bash for $SHELL

Tags: shell, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am using Vagrant to run my ubuntu 14.04 OS.

the $SHELL value for my vagrant user is `/bin/sh`.

I tried to run `chsh` to change to `/bin/bash` but Vagrant does not allow this.

How do I change the $SHELL to `/bin/bash`  for the vagrant user?

When I vagrant ssh and tried the `chsh -s /binbash vagrant`, I got the following:

[image]

Comment: What is the error when you do `chsh -s /binbash vagrant`? Remember the password for user `root` and `vagrant` is `vagrant`.

Comment: @TerryWang See question for the error.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot a sudo (and a slash):

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash vagrant
```

Provision it directly from vagrant:

```
config.vm.provision :shell do |shell|
    shell.inline = "sudo chsh -s /bin/bash vagrant"
end
```

If you are already using puppet, its as simple as

```
user { 'vagrant':
    shell      => '/bin/bash',
}
```

in your puppetfile.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're wanting to change default shell as a normal user. You can add this to your `~/.profile`:

```
[ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ] && exec /bin/bash -l
```

Comment: Is there a way to use Vagrant file instead?

Comment: Okay this worked, but I had to change `~/.profile` inside `vagrant` user. Hopefully there is another way to use Vagrant file instead.

Comment: @KimStacks What Vagrant file is exactly the one you needed to change?

Comment: Vagrantfile The one that contains the config. Text looks like this: VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION...